# What was the effect of freeing Calypso?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

> The King and his men stole the Queen from her bed
>   And bound her in her bones
>   The seas be ours and by the powers
>   Where we will we'll roam

The first Brethren Court with the help of Davy Jones, trapped Calypso and bound her in human form as Tia Dalma. Since Calypso is the sea goddess, this tamed the seas, even seeming to give the pirates control over them.

Presumably, freeing Calypso from her human form returned that power to her. She summons a maelstrom that swallows Davy Jones and *The Flying Dutchman*.

**But after that, do we ever see the effects of a freed Calypso?**

This can be in the final acts of *At World's End*, or in the sequels, such as *On Stranger Tides* or *Dead Men Tell No Tales* / *Salazar's Revenge*.